# Find if ABAP keyword is valid for a given ABAP version

Tags: abap

I'd like to know how to tell if a keyword is valid in an older version of ABAP. If I write something like:

```
DATA(l_foo) = cl_lorem->ipsum( l_bar ).
```

How can I tell what version of ABAP would be required to run that statement?  This would be helpful for answering others' questions when they say something ridiculous like "I'm on a 4.6C system".

Comment: If you have different systems available, you could write a RFC to upload the program and execute a syntax check. Then you can output the result per system. Some hints for the RFC could be in http://www.dalestech.com/products/syntaxchecker.htm

Comment: If I had different systems available, I would just copy and paste the program and execute a syntax check, or look up the ABAP keyword in each's documentation.

Comment: In which ABAP version is this statement compilable?

Comment: This is from the new 7.4.  The inline data declarations are a pretty drastic change.

Comment: @Eric +1 for making me aware there is some new stuff like that.

Answer (score 1):

You could logon to the newest system you have at hand, open the `ABAPDOCU` and walk through the release-specific information there manually. I doubt there's a built-in system available to check this automatically.

Comment: Fair enough.  I wasn't necessarily looking for a way to find the version via some program, I just hoped there was another way than this, i.e. a list of all keywords and when they were introduced.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use the documentation from SAP to find a keywords available for a specific ABAP version.

- [Release news](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/abennews.htm)
  Select the release of interest and check which features were introduced.
- [ABAP Index](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/abenabap_index.htm)
  The list of keywords with links the appropriate documentation for the latest ABAP version.
- [ABAP Words  Overview](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/abenabap_words.htm)
  An overview of ABAP words for the latest ABAP version.

You can go from the *release news* to the *specific version* in question and find the list of keywords for it.

I will also leave a link to [Clean ABAP](https://github.com/SAP/styleguides/blob/main/clean-abap/CleanABAP.md) guideline as a summary of experience in writing ABAP and using different language features.